# Why doesn't this dropdown menu display properly?

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

So, I'm trying to make a nice stylish CSS3 menu for my first ever website, but I can't get the thing to work :( I've tried different displays, positions, clear: both, all sort of stuff, nothing got the thing done. + I can't seem to get the thing to work with:

```
.subnav {
  display: none;
}
li:hover>subnav {
  display: block;
}
```

so I left it shown at all times and try to position the thing correctly, then I'd either add javascript for showing on hover or try to fix this, if you can help with both that'd be great.
Oh, and I didn't remove the styling in case some of it interfere with what I try to achieve.
Here's the html:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li id="active">Menu1</li>
   <li>Menu2</li>
   <ul class="subnav">
     <li>Submenu</li>
     <li>Submenu</li>
     <li>Submenu</li>
   </ul>
   <li>Menu</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

and css:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 5px 0 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: #3498db;
  color: white;
}
#active {
  background: #34495e;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
.subnav{
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  top: 40px;
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Your `.subnav` is outside li, bring it inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the subnav inside `li` and then `li:hover > .subnav` would work.

`li:hover > .subnav` means you are searching for .subnav under li

```css
.subnav {
  display: none;
}
li:hover> .subnav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li id="active">Menu1</li>
   <li>Menu2
    <ul class="subnav">
     <li>Submenu</li>
     <li>Submenu</li>
     <li>Submenu</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
  
   <li>Menu</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think it might be that simple, I spent hours trying to solve it and seen many tutorials on it, but I would never guess the answer!

Comment: @Nech Glad to help. It happens to everyone :). Sometimes we just miss the most obvious thing.